# VS Code says: It is not recommended to run Code as root user. This isn't intended

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't want to run as a root user and I'm not sure how I got there. How do I revert back?

Comment: Are you trying to run Visual Studio Code from the terminal, for example with `code` or `code-insiders`, or just clicking the icon in your applications menu?

Comment: Applications menu this time.  I often do both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with VSCode not being correctly installed in the applications directory in my situation.